# Принцип работы и использования облачного объектного хранилища

Tags: облачное-хранилище

Для для мобильного приложения необходимо сохранять файлы. Есть backend с базой данных. Я не могу понять, файлы можно ведь сохранять сразу с мобильного приложения в облако, но! Это получается в приложении должны быть ключи, которые нужны для работы с облаком, не опасно ли это? Или необходимо загружать файл с приложения на сервер, а оттуда на облако? Кажется не целесообразным гонять файлы туда сюда, это ведь время на загрузку на сервер, а потом на облако? Или подскажите литературу или статью об использовании облачных хранилищ и архитектуре таких решений. Думаю что в работе с облаком не один подход, и нужно подобрать оптимальный для проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы доступа к хранилищу используется следующий подход.

Когда мобильному приложению требуется, например, прочитать данные, оно запрашивает backend сервер, который генерирует временную ссылку на файл в хранилище. Эта ссылка дает доступ к одному файлу на протяжении ограниченого периода времени. Мобильное приложение использует ее для доступа к файлу напрямую.

Это работает как для чтения, так и для модификации или создания.

Условно код в мобильном приложении будет делать загрузку файла так:

```
URL tempUploadURL = myBackend.generateTemporaryUrlForUpload();
// tempUploadURL содержит URL который указывает в облако
http.put(tempUploadURL, fileContent, headers={'content-length': ...})
```

Вот [тут](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) и [тут](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html) описание для AWS S3. [Тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) для azure.

Comment: Т.е. для загрузки всеравно необходимо загрузить файл на сервер, а после уже в облако?

Comment: Нет. Для загрузки мобильное приложение точно так же делает запрос на сервер, сервер возвращает временный URL (указывающий на облачное хранилище), который мобильное приложение использует для загрузки файла.

Comment: А не могут ли злоумышленники раздобыв ключи, забить облачное хранилище? Ведь оно денег стоит. Я просто только знакомлюсь с этой технологией и пока не понимаю даже базовых принципов.

Comment: И я планирую использовать услуги Казахстанской компании. Не знаю, важно это или нет. Думаю, что в плане безопасности все же лучше будут зарубежные игроки, но они не подходят.

Comment: Уточняющие вопросы не понятны. Кажется, они выходят за рамки оригинального вопроса (если нет - дополните вопрос, если смогу - отвечу), ну и комментарии не для подробных ответов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, хоть немного но помогли. Думаю лучшим решением будет потратить достаточно времени, что бы разобраться для начала с основами.